# Printing space and new lines within a loop issue

Tags: loops, assembly, newline, mips, space

The code i wrote works however during the second loop and onward the newlines and the 'totalmin' string isn't printed. can someone please tell me how to fix this? the loop is correct because the printed values (without the spaces) are correct

im using mars 4.4 and also used the code in 4.3 but the output was the same
Code:

```
#a1 is the minvalue base address for the minterms
#a2 holds value 1 
#a3 holds minvalue[i]
#t0 is the counter 
#t1 is the counter*4
#t2 holds the value of bit0[i]
#t3 holds the value of bit1[i]
#t4 holds the value of bit2[i]
#t5 holds the value of bit3[i]
#t6 holds the value of the compliment of bit0[i]....second use uses t6 as the product of bit0^bit1'
#t7 holds the value of bit2^bit3.... second use uses t7 as the product of (bit2^bit3)xor(bit1^bit0')
#t9 holds the min number
#s0 is the minvalue base address+(counter*4)
#s1 is the bit0 base address
#s2 is the bit1 base address
#s3 is the bit2 base address
#s4 is the bit3 base address
#s5 is the bit0 base address+(counter*4)
#s6 is the bit1 base address+(counter*4)
#s7 is the bit2 base address+(counter*4)
#t8 is the bit3 base address+(counter*4)
.data
bit0: .word 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 #array which holds values of bit zero
bit1: .word 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1 #array which holds values of bit one
bit2: .word 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1 #array which holds values of bit two
bit3: .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 #array which holds values of bit three

minvalue: .word 0   #array which holds the min term for each value 

space: .asciiz "   "                #creates a space when printing
newline: .asciiz "\n"               #creates a new line when printing
totalmin: .asciiz "the number of Minterms in F is:  "

.text
la $a1, minvalue        #base address for minterms
la $s1, bit0            #base address for bit0
la $s2, bit1            #base address for bit1
la $s3, bit2            #base address for bit2
la $s4, bit3            #base address for bit3  

li $t0, 0           #t0 is the counter which is set to 0
li $a2, 1           #a2 holds value 1
li $t9, 0           #min number is set to 0

loop:
sll $t1, $t0, 2         #multiplies the current value of t0 by 4 or t1=i*4
add $s0, $a1, $t1       #adds the minvalue base address by 4 each loop or s0=   minvbase+(i*4)
add $s5, $s1, $t1       #adds the bit0 base address by 4 each loop or s5= bit0base+(i*4)
add $s6, $s2, $t1       #adds the bit1 base address by 4 each loop or s6= bit1base+(i*4)
add $s7, $s3, $t1       #adds the bit2 base address by 4 each loop or s7= bit2base+(i*4)
add $t8, $s4, $t1       #adds the bit3 base address by 4 each loop or t8=bit3base+(i*4) 

lw $t2, 0($s5)          #t2 holds the value of bit0[i]
lw $t3, 0($s6)          #t3 holds the value of bit1[i]
lw $t4, 0($s7)          #t4 holds the value of bit2[i]
lw $t5, 0($t8)          #t5 holds the value of bit3[i]

not $t6, $t2            #t6 holds the value of the compliment of bit0[i]
and $t6, $t6, $t3       #t6 holds the value of bit1^bit0'
and $t7, $t4, $t5       #t7 holds the value of bit2^bit3
xor $t7, $t7, $t6       #t7 holds the value of (bit2^bit3)xor(bit1^bit0')

sw $zero, 0($s0)        #minterm[i] is intially set to zero
bne $t7, 0, minterm1        #if t7 is 1 then jump to minterm1

print:
lw $a3, 0($s0)          #a3 holds the value of minvalue[i]

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t4
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, space
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $a3
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1        #increment counter or i++
bge $t0, 16, exit       #if t0 >= 16 jump to exit
j loop              #else jump to loop 


minterm1:
sw $a2, 0($s0)          #rewrites the minterm[i] from zero to 1
addi $t9, $t9, 1        #min number= min number+1
j print

exit:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, totalmin
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t9
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

output:

!http://puu.sh/7N1hx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minvalue: .word 0   #array which holds the min term for each value
```

The array you've declared only has space for a single 32-bit word, so your loop ends up overwriting other data located after `minvalue`.

If you meant for `minvalue` to hold 16 words you should use something like:

```
minvalue: .space 16*4
```